# How to reduce node spacing in forest when using a custom edge path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\title{Bla}
\author{John Doe}
\date{April 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
      grow=east,
      parent anchor=east,
      child anchor=west,
      align=center,
      l=1em, l sep+=0em,anchor=base west,inner sep=0.1pt,outer sep=0pt,
       edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
      for root={
        parent anchor=east,
      },
    }
    [Main BLA,rotate=90,child anchor=north, parent anchor=south, anchor=center
      [Quebec1234
            [Romeo
                ]
            [Sierra
                ]
      ]
      [Alpha123
          [India12345]
          [Foxtrot,parent anchor=0
            [Golf12345,edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- +(50pt,0pt) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },before drawing tree={x+=44pt,y+=0pt}]
            [Hotel1234567890,edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- +(50pt,0pt) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },before drawing tree={x+=44pt,y+=0pt}]
          ]
          [Echo123456]
          [Delta12345]
          [Charlie123]
          [Bravo12345]
     ]
    ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

Which gives me the following output:

[image: forest]

I want to reduce the empty (vertical) space between node `Echo123456` and `Foxtrot` as well as `India12345` and `Foxtrot`. I am aware of `s sep`, but I am not sure how I can apply it only to `Foxtrot`. For example, when I set it to node `Foxtrot`, it will reduce the space for nodes `Hotel1234567890` and `Golf12345`. Instead, if I set it at the `Alpha123` level, all children will be affected (and not just `Foxtrot`).

Desired outcome:

[image: forest2]

Comment: I think you're looking for `fit = tight`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel On the `Foxtrot` level, like `[Foxtrot,parent anchor=0,fit = tight`? Because this doesn't seem to produce the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of `forked edge` and added coordinate vertex after "Foxtrot" node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}  % added option

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
    grow=east,
    anchor=west,
% edges
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
    s sep = 1mm,            % added 
    l sep = 6mm,            % changed
 fork sep = 3mm,            % added distance from parent to branching point
    }
[Main BLA, rotate=90,anchor=center
    [Quebec1234
        [Romeo]
        [Sierra]
    ]
    [Alpha123
        [India12345]
        [Foxtrot,
            [,coordinate        % <--- inserted
                [Golf12345]
                [Hotel1234567890]
            ]
        ]
        [Echo123456]
        [Delta12345]
        [Charlie123]
        [Bravo12345]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

As you can observe, removed are all code for edges used in your MWE. Hopeful, result is close what you like to get:

[image]